# Having trouble uploading a file via requests library to API

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to automate a manual process, which requires hitting an endpoint and uploading a file, in addition to providing other form data.  I'm receiving a `400 Bad Request` with my Python code.

Here is a `curl` request that works:

```
curl -X POST "https://xxxx/backfill" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "rsid=some_rsid" -F "file=@300038045-backfill.txt;type=text/plain" -H "Authorization: Basic xxx"
```

Here is the Python code:

```
def create_backfill(backfill_url: str, rsid: str, file_path: str, auth: Tuple[str, str]):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
    form_data = {'rsid': rsid}
    files = {'file': (os.path.basename(file_path), open(file_path, 'rb'), 'text/plain')}
    response = requests.post(backfill_url, data=form_data, files=files, headers=headers, auth=auth)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()
```

Not sure exactly what I'm doing incorrectly

EDIT:
I ran both requests through `https://httpbin.org`, and got these results

Curl:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {
    "file": "data\n"
  },
  "form": {
    "rsid": "some_rsid"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic xxx",
    "Content-Length": "448",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------929813e67050b28c",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0"
  },
  "json": null,
  "origin": "192.150.9.200, 192.150.9.200",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Python:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Authorization": "Basic xxx", 
    "Content-Length": "32", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.22.0"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "192.150.9.200, 192.150.9.200", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/
```

Comment: try reading this and modify your post request accordingly  r"""Sends a POST request.

    :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
    :param data: (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like
        object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param json: (optional) json data to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    :return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
    :rtype: requests.Response
    """

Comment: have you tried replacing `data=form_data` with `json=form_data`?